# Using cut and bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to cut this line

```
`Cycling-Tour.Of.Great.Britain.Results-Cycling.txt`
 to
`cycling-tour.of.great.britain.txt`
```

so I'm looking to remove the part .Results-cycling using cut in a bash script with no luck I've tried

```
`txtname=$(echo "$txtname" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | cut -d "-" -f2,11)`
```

which sort the uppercasing out but it removes most of the line.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `txtname="${txtname,,}"; txtname="${txtname%-*}.${txtname##*.}"`

Comment: You need to be careful about the backquotes (`).  Bash will execute the string as a command and then try to execute the result.  Use forward quotes (') or double quotes (").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$ name='Cycling-Tour.Of.Great.Britain.Results-Cycling.txt'
```

To lower case

```
$ echo ${name,,}
cycling-tour.of.great.britain.results-cycling.txt
```

And to remove 'Results-Cycling'

```
$ lower=${name,,}
$ echo ${lower//.results-cycling/}
cycling-tour.of.great.britain.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

`bash` has decent string parsing. There are options without spawning so many subprocesses.

use

```
$: declare -l txtname
```

first and you don't have to worry about case any more.

```
$: txtname=Cycling-Tour.Of.Great.Britain.Results-Cycling.txt
$: IFS=. read a b c d x e <<< "$txtname"
$: echo "$a.$b.$c.$d.$e"
cycling-tour.of.great.britain.txt
```

or just

```
echo "${txtname/results-cycling.}"
cycling-tour.of.great.britain.txt
```

If you just wanted to use `cut` -

```
$: cut -d . -f 1-4,6 <<< "${txtname,,}"
cycling-tour.of.great.britain.txt
```

Comment: Just use `IFS=. read ...`; you specifically *don't* want additional field-splitting based on the current value of `IFS`.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I also needed to quote the var for the same general reasons...

Answer (score 1):

```
prefix=$(echo "Cycling-Tour.Of.Great.Britain.Results-Cycling.txt" | cut -d'.' -f1-4 | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')

echo "${prefix}.txt"
```

It's OK to spawn subprocesses.